# Custom Attributes/User defined attributes using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, user-defined-types

Is there a Ruby gem that helps us to build apps that allow the users to define custom attributes for the application entities/forms? This is very common on ERP or CRM apps.

I looked at https://github.com/latortuga/has_magic_columns, it looks promising, but the README says it is not production-ready. I also didn't liked the fact that the code store different data types in the same string column.

I can use NoSQL databases to help me store the custom attributes in a schemaless database, but I still have to create a database structure that stores the custom attribute configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into the new rails 4 active record hstore? This allows you to store key value pairs right inside PostgreSQL.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveRecord::Store which came out in Rails 3.2. It gives you exactly what you're looking for:

- store that serializes into one text column in the database
- you put any attributes inside as you wish
- additionally you can define accessors for common attributes

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :color, :homepage ], coder: JSON
end

u = User.new(color: 'black', homepage: '37signals.com')
u.color                          # Accessor stored attribute
u.settings[:country] = 'Denmark' # Any attribute, even if not specified with an accessor

# There is no difference between strings and symbols for accessing custom attributes
u.settings[:country]  # => 'Denmark'
u.settings['country'] # => 'Denmark'

# Add additional accessors to an existing store through store_accessor
class SuperUser < User
  store_accessor :settings, :privileges, :servants
end
```

Pasted from / more information:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html